# Exception from loading Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage when creating a new HiveConnection

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-hdinsight

I had this code working:

```
ClusterDetails details

return new HiveConnection(
      new Uri(details.ConnectionUrl),
      details.HttpUserName,
      details.HttpPassword,
      details.DefaultStorageAccount.Name,
      details.DefaultStorageAccount.Key);
```

but when I updated the dlls through Nuget, I started getting this exception:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"}

Here is my packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.6.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Hadoop.Client" version="1.1.0.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Hadoop.Hive" version="0.12.5126.42915" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="1.8.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight" version="1.1.0.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="3.0.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

I've gone through and manually checked all of the dlls in the bin directory to make sure that the versions match. I've also checked to make sure that they all match the latest versions on Nuget.

I've tried adding variations this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.3.0" newVersion="3.0.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

to the app.config, but it just creates a new exception in a different part of the code.

```
IHDInsightClient _client;
var details = await _client.CreateClusterAsync(clusterInfo);
```

This code fails with the following exception:

> {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: provider"}

This happens regardless of which version of the dll I tell it to use. I had v2.2 of the SDK installed outside of this. I uninstalled it, but that did not help.

At this point, I'm out of ideas and falling behind on a deadline because of it. Has anyone run into this before? Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 3.1.0.1 of the storage library was released yesterday (I've been dealing with this issue since Sunday). Updating to that fixed the issue.