# Create HDCluster using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-powershell

I am trying to create cluster using powershell. Here is script I am executing:

```
$containerName = "hdfiles"
$location = "Southeast Asia"
$clusterNodes = 2
$userName = "HDUser"

#Generate random password
$rand = New-Object System.Random
$pass = ""
$pass = $pass + [char]$rand.next(97,121) #lower case
$pass = $pass + [char]$rand.next(48,57) #number
$pass = $pass + [char]$rand.next(65,90) #upper case
$pass = $pass + [char]$rand.next(58,62) #special character
1..6 | ForEach { $pass = $pass + [char]$rand.next(97,121) } #6 lower-case characters
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force

# generate unique random cluster and storage account names
do
{
  $clusterName = "hd"
  1..6 | ForEach { $clusterName = $clusterName + [char]$rand.next(48,57) }
  $storageAccountName = $clusterName + "store"
}
while ((Test-AzureName -Name $storageAccountName -Storage) -and (Test-AzureName -Name $clusterName -Service))

# Create a storage account
Write-Host "Creating storage account..."
New-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -Location $location

# Create a Blob storage container
Write-Host "Creating container..."
$storageAccountKey = Get-AzureStorageKey $storageAccountName | %{ $_.Primary }
$destContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Context $destContext

# Create a cluster
Write-Host "Creating HDInsight cluster..."
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName, $password)
New-AzureHDInsightCluster -Name $clusterName -Location $location -DefaultStorageAccountName "$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net" -DefaultStorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey -DefaultStorageContainerName $containerName -ClusterSizeInNodes $clusterNodes -Credential $credential -Version 3.2
```

But on last line I am getting exception:

```
New-AzureHDInsightCluster : Validating connection to 'hd662173store.blob.core.windows.net' failed. Inner exception:Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
At D:\ProgrammingWorkspace\Edx\Processing BigData with HDInsight\HDILabs\Lab02A\Provision HDInsight.ps1:38 char:1 + New-AzureHDInsightCluster -Name $clusterName -Location $location -Def ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureHDInsightCluster], ConfigurationErrorsException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.Cmdlet.PSCmdlets.NewAzureHDInsightClusterCmdlet
```

I am using Azure Powershell release 0.9.7 and Azure SDK 2.7

Comment: Edit to add: My apologies!  Turned out the keyword I searched was in the Related section.  Have you tried re-installing the Azure SDK and rebooting?  And check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841556/exception-from-loading-microsoft-windowsazure-storage-when-creating-a-new-hiveco

Comment: Yes, few times. Actually in SDK folder I have this lib, but version is 5.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking back on this, the issue you encountered is likely now fixed with the latest version of Azure PowerShell.

To install the latest version of Azure PowerShell, see here:
[Installing Azure PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/)

For samples of how to use HDInsight PowerShell cmdlets (e.g., New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster), see here: [Using HDInsight Azure PowerShell cmdlets](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-administer-use-powershell/)

I hope this helps!