# New-AzureHDInsightCluster / Get-AzureHDInsightJobStatus error

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-hdinsight

Since the updated version of Azure PowerShell (0.9.7) was released on August 14th 2015, I'm getting the following error whenever I run **New-AzureHDInsightCluster** or **Get-AzureHDInsightJobStatus**. Both worked without issue before installing the new release. Any ideas?

> Validating connection to '*storageacct*.blob.core.windows.net' failed. Inner
>   exception:Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

The new PowerShell release uses Azure Resource Manager mode instead of Azure Service mode.  For more information on the ARM mode, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/ and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager/

First you need to decide which mode to use. Either way, I would recommended to use the following cmdlet to confirm the mode you are in:

Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager

The following article shows you how to provision a cluster using the ARM mode.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-provision-clusters/#provision-tools

Comment: I think the following thread will actually answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155732/create-hdcluster-using-powershell